# Amazon Redshift ODBC connection EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, odbc, amazon-redshift

I'm not able to connect to my Redshift cluster through ODBC from an EC2 instance. However, I'm able to connect to it from an outside computer (for eg My Macbook) using the ODBC connector. I have been trying and trying but in vain. How can I make my EC2 instance connect to Redshift? The Error I get is:

**Is the Server running on host .................and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5439?**
I'm really confused as I can connect form outside but not from an EC2. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, security group settings for any group associated with the Redshift instance, whether you're using the same software to connect (is your EC2 instance running Windows vs you accessing locally from a Mac?). The question is whether the problem is due to connecting differently vs connecting from EC2.

Comment: The EC2 instance has a VPC-ID of say X, the Redshift Cluster has a VPC-ID of say Y. There is no 'security' for Redshift because my account does not support the EC2 Instance platform. I have VPC security groups. The said Redshift cluster has a default subnet group of VPC-ID Y. My EC2 instance is Windows. Do you need any more information? @John Rotenstein

Comment: Okay, so your EC2 instance and Redshift cluster are in separate VPCs, eh? Security Groups *do* apply to Redshift via an [Amazon Redshift Cluster Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-security-groups.html). It's worth checking the configuration. Have you tried connecting from an "outside" Windows computer to Redshift, with the same software as you're using on the Windows EC2 instance? That would help isolate potential causes of your issue. Also, can your Windows EC2 instance access the Internet (eg a web site) okay?

Answer (score 0):

Add the security group of your EC2 machine to the list of Ingress rules of the security group in your Redshift VPC.

Basically, you need to allow your EC2 machine to connect to the Redshift cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the instance in the same VPC, public hostname of redshift might not work.